# How to create simulink.parameter for list of signal names from Excel or a structure

Tags: matlab, simulink

It might look simple buts it's consuming lot of my time. Below is the code which will not work.

I want to create Simulink.parameter of all the variable names listed in Excel or in a structure.

```
Calibration = {'Var1';'Var2';'Var3';'Var'};

for i = numel(Calibration)
   Calibration (1,i) = Simulink.Parameter;
end
```

///////////
I know the above way of creating simulink.parameter is wrong, we can assign it like that, guide me the way to do the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your code is almost correct.

This version works with arrays:

```
Calibration = {'Var1';'Var2';'Var3';'Var'};

for i = 1:numel(Calibration)
   simPar(1,i) = Simulink.Parameter;
end
```

then you can access them using:

```
simPar(1)
simPar(1).Value
...
```

Here you need to use a different variable to store the parameters, you cannot reuse Calibration

---

This version works with CELL arrays:

```
Calibration = {'Var1';'Var2';'Var3';'Var'};

for i = 1:numel(Calibration)
   Calibration{1,i} = Simulink.Parameter;
end
```

then you can access them using:

```
Calibration{1}
Calibration{1}.Value
```

Here you can reuse the Calibration variable, and for whatever reason, overwrite it.

---

The 2 issues you had in your code were:

- Calibration is a cell array and you are trying to assign to it as if it was a regular array
- the loop is not well defined. The index is not changing, it's a static 4.

---

Following the comments i added this code to the answer.

**Disclaimer**: i don't recommend creating variable names programmatically. It is bad practice and so is the use of eval. I think you should go for an alternative method by reformulating your problem (ie using structs or arrays). Anyways:

```
Calibration = {'Var1';'Var2';'Var3';'Var'};

for i = 1:numel(Calibration)
   eval(sprintf('%s=Simulink.Parameter',Calibration{i,1}))
end
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But this will not work. It will just create simulink.parameter for name starts with indexing. For example: Calibration [1,1] as parameter name, I want naming as element names in this structure.  Var1, Var2 ... As simulink.parameter objects

Comment: i edited my answer to fit you request